# If statement Big Query

Tags: sql, function, if-statement, google-bigquery

I'm quite new user of big query with basic SQL skills.
I would like to build a query that is using a conditional IF statement to add a new value in one of my field

Here is the data that i have

```
    YEAR  |  MONTH   | NEW YEAR
----------+----------+-------------
     2018 | April    | 
     2019 | June     | 
     2020 | May      |
```

I was thinking about the following request :

```
Select
IF (YEAR ="2018" AND MONTH=April) THEN (NEW YEAR =2019),
IF (YEAR ="2019" AND MONTH=June) THEN (NEW YEAR =2020),
IF (YEAR ="2020" AND MONTH=May) THEN (NEW YEAR =2021)
FROM 'database'
WHERE source ='name source'
```

i'm trying to figure out, but impossible to set the right syntax and logic

Many thanks for your help
Much appreciated !

Comment: Perhaps you want UPDATE, not SELECT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (case when YEAR = '2018' and month = 'April' then 2019
             when YEAR = '2019' and month = 'June' then 2020
             when YEAR = '2020' and month = 'May' then 2021
        end) as NEW YEAR
FROM `database`
WHERE source = 'name source'
```

Comment: i have the following error : No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [3:14]

Comment: @whands . . . Storing the year as a string seems strange to me, but that is easily fixed.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it's working perfectly fine. now i'm just trying to find a way to optimize the request. How can i do to define range YEAR-MONTH and set the value of the NEW YEAR. Otherwise i will need to copy/paste and the request will be quite long. Thanks for your help

Comment: @whands . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  This answers the question that you have asked here.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you forgot to mention what exactly logic you want to be implemented for your new column - but at least below fixes the issue with using IF statement

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CASE (year, month) 
    WHEN ('2018', 'April') THEN 2019
    WHEN ('2019', 'June') THEN 2020
    WHEN ('2020', 'May') THEN 2021   
  END AS new_year
FROM 'database'
WHERE source ='name source'
```